# Understanding Firebase data binding with user identifiers

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Guys I am trying to learn Firebase framework and I do have question about storing data, so as I understood, the data is stored as entire `JSON` file in the Firebase database.

Let's say I have few data models (just to simplify my description):

Users and Articles

Using Firebase SDK we can simple create user using very simple query. The Firebase user has `uid` which I can use for my purposes. My general question right now is how to bind `uid` with my data.

Correct me if I am wrong but I plan to use `uid` retrieved from the Firebase to create few nodes in Realtime DataBase like these:

```
{
  "users": {
    "$uid": {
    "name": "Alex",
    "lastname": "Matrosov"
  },
  "$uid": {
    "name": "John",
    "lastname": "Malkovich"
  }
  }
}
```

So when I create/sign in user I plan to add related info to the users/user node.

Then I want to store user article

```
{
      "articles": {
        "$article_id": {
        "name": "Some name",
        "$uid": "32431kjkjfj232"
      },
      "$article_id": {
        "name": "Some name",
        "$uid": "5555fffflllll"
      }
      }
    }
```

So as I understood right when I will request articles it will contain all articles? Let me know if I am on right way with understanding of this uid and data binding.

Comment: Well... Firebase database is just like any other database. How do you bind a user to an article in a MySQL database? You create an `article` entity with a `userId` reference, or when doing a two-way binding - a `user` entity referencing all his `articles`. There's nothing special here - you can do just the same in Firebase.

Comment: ok got it, yea seems I found an example here [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'd say you're almost right. Just a few notes:

1. Inside article's JSON structure, since the '$' dollar mark on '$uid' field, usually, refers to a variable on firebase's database, I'd recommend you to change it to something else like 'userUID' or anything you want. Leaving the structure to something like this:

   ```
   {
     "articles": {
       "$article_id": {
         "name": "Some name",
         "userUID": "32431kjkjfj232"
       },
       "$article_id": {
         "name": "Some name",
         "userUID": "5555fffflllll"
       }
     }
   }
   ```
2. Then, you just query them as follow:

#### Using Swift 4 and Firebase 4:

```
let articlesRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "articles")

articlesRef.observe(.value) { snapshot in
    // Snopshot will contain all articles on your db reference.
    print(snapshot)
}

let userUID = "..."
let articlesByUser = articlesRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "userUID").queryEqual(toValue: userUID)

articlesByUser.observe(.value) { snapshot in
    // In this case, snapshot will contain all articles that has the 'userUID' key equal to what you've passed (what in this case, is the value of userUID constant.)
    print(snapshot)
}
```